# Seaborn: How to change size of spots in a JointPlot according to feature?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, data-visualization, visualization

I have codes below. You can see that a JointPlot is plotted.

But I want the size of dots to change with the values of the column "size".

So I changed the last line `marker='o')` to `marker='o', s = "size")`. Now I have error message `AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 's'`.

I want each spot size to be different (i.e. similar to [this](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/277-marginal-histogram-for-ggplot2_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-1-1.png)). How can I modify my code to achieve this?

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
sns.set(style="darkgrid")

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.jointplot("total_bill", "tip", data=tips, kind="reg",
                  xlim=(0, 60), ylim=(0, 12), color='k', size = 7)

#Clear the axes containing the scatter plot
g.ax_joint.cla()

# #Plot each individual point separately
for i,row in enumerate(tips.values):
    g.ax_joint.plot(row[0], row[1], color="blue", marker='o')
```

**Updates:**

I also tried to combine two plots directly, but still doesn't work. There is no error, but the scatterplot is just pasted to the right...

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import product
sns.set(style="darkgrid")

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

g = sns.jointplot("total_bill", "tip", data=tips, kind="reg",
                  xlim=(0, 60), ylim=(0, 12), color='k', size = 7)

#Clear the axes containing the scatter plot
g.ax_joint.cla()

ax2 = ax.twinx()

sns.scatterplot(
    data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="size", size="size",
    sizes=(20, 200), legend="full"
)

plt.show()
```

Comment: @JohanC Thanks. In the last line, `g.ax_joint.scatter(row[0], row[1], color="blue", marker='o', s=7)` works, but `g.ax_joint.scatter(row[0], row[1], color="blue", marker='o', s="size")` still doesn't work, which is my main intention... I want the dots to have different size...

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` doesn't work here, because `jointplot` is a figure-level function that creates a new figure.  You need `sns.scatterplot(..., ax=g.ax_joint)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a seaborn scatterplot on `g.ax_joint`. The following code has been tested with seaborn 0.11.2 (older versions may have a problem with a column named 'size').

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

sns.set(style="darkgrid")

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.jointplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips, kind="reg",
                  xlim=(0, 60), ylim=(0, 12), color='k')
g.ax_joint.cla()
sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x='total_bill', y='tip', size='size', sizes=(10, 200),
                ax=g.ax_joint)
```

[image: sns.jointplot with adapted scatterplot]

As mentioned in the comments, to keep the regression line, `sns.jointplot(..., scatter=False)` can be used.

```py
g = sns.jointplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips, kind="reg", scatter=False,
                  xlim=(0, 60), ylim=(0, 12), color='k')
sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x='total_bill', y='tip',
                hue='size', palette='husl',
                size='size', sizes=(10, 200), legend='full',
                ax=g.ax_joint)
```

[image: jointplot using sizes in the scatterplot]

Comment: Perhaps do `scatter=False` in the `jointplot` call and then don't clear the axes, that way you'll get the size mapping and a regression line (which seems desired)?